# Prove inequality with MVT

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

I want to prove the following inequality using the first mean value theorem for integrals: \begin{equation*}1\leq \int_0^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{1+x^2}\, dx\leq \frac{1}{4-2\sqrt{2}}e^{\left (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right )}\approx 1,1440\end{equation*}

$$$$

The first mean value theorem for integrals is the following:

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$. Then there exists $\xi \in (a, b)$ with \begin{equation*}\int_a^bf(x)\, dx=f(\xi)(b-a)\end{equation*}

Right? 
$$$$

How can we apply this proposition to show the inequality? I got stuck right now. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Indeed, your first step is correct. Now note that as a consequence, $ \int_{[a,b]} f \le (b-a) \max_{\xi \in [a,b]} f(\xi),$ and similarly with $ \ge$ and $ \min_{\xi \in [a,b]} f(\xi).$ This reduces the problem to computing these extrema (and indeed, that is where the expressions above come from).

Comment: I totally agree with @stochasticboy321's comment (except for a missing factor of $(b-a)$ on the second inequality. But I think there's an arithmetic error in the computation of the maximum value on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could we get a better approximation if we use the second mean value theorem for integrals? From this theorem we have \begin{equation*}\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\, dx=f(a)\int_a^{\xi}g(x)\, dx+f(b)\int_{\xi}^bg(x)\, dx\end{equation*} Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $g(x)=e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}$. Then we have the following:

Comment: @TedShifrin $$\int_0^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{1+x^2}\, dx=f(0)\cdot \int_0^{\xi}g(x)\, dx+f(1)\cdot \int_{\xi}^1g(x)\, dx \\=1\cdot \int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{\xi}^1e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx = \int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx$$

Comment: @TedShifrin $$\\ =\int_0^{1}\left (e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\right )\, dx =\left [\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\right ]_0^1 \\=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}-\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ Is this correct? Using this theorem we get an equality, so it is better to use this one, or not?

Comment: No, you made an error. Where did $\xi$ go? Remember that the theorem just says that it works for *some* particular $\xi$!

Comment: So, just till $\int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx$ it is correct, isn't it? What can we do next? @TedShifrin

Comment: You could minimize and maximize that function of $\xi\in [0,1]$, I suppose. I don't see why you're going to all this trouble. The original approach was correct, except for a miscalculation in the problem itself.

Comment: I wanted to see if we get a better approximation of the integral using the second mean value theorem for integrals. Or do we get the same approximation? @TedShifrin

Comment: It seems to give a totally different set of bounds, and worse ones, at that.

Comment: We have that $$\int_0^{\xi}\min_{x\in[0,\xi]}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\min_{x\in[\xi,1]}\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx\leq\int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx\leq \int_0^{\xi}\max_{x\in[0,\xi]}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\max_{x\in[\xi,1]}\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx\\ $$

Comment: $$\Rightarrow \int_0^{\xi}e^{0}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\frac{e^{\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx\leq\int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx\leq \int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx \\ \Rightarrow \xi+\frac{e^{\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}(1-\xi)\leq\int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx\leq e^{\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}}\xi+\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}(1-\xi)$$ Or am I thinking wrong? @TedShifrin

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You have a function of $\xi$. You know the original integral is equal to that function evaluated at some particular $\xi\in [0,1]$. Therefore the integral is between the minimum and maximum values of that function of $\xi$. Just use usual techniques to find those.

Comment: I thought about that again. We have that $$\int_0^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{1+x^2}\, dx=f(0)\cdot \int_0^{\xi}g(x)\, dx+f(1)\cdot \int_{\xi}^1g(x)\, dx \\=1\cdot \int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{\xi}^1e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx = \int_0^{\xi}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}\, dx+\ \int_{\xi}^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\, dx \\ =\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}}-\sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}=-\sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}$$

Comment: So we get $$\int_0^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{1+x^2}\, dx=-\sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}$$ and so $$-\sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{0}}{2}\leq \int_0^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{1+x^2}\, dx\leq -\sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}\\\Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq \int_0^1\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{1+x^2}\, dx\leq -\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$Is this correct? @TedShifrin

Comment: Or am I still thinking wrong? @TedShifrin

Comment: Yes, that's what I got too. (Please factor things when possible rather than multiplying out all the constants.) As I said, worse bounds.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much! @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$f(x):=\frac{\exp(x/\sqrt{2})}{1+x^2}$$
has derivative equal to 
$$f'(x)=\frac{\exp(x/\sqrt{2})(1-2\sqrt{2}x+x^2)}{\sqrt{2}(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{\exp(x/\sqrt{2})((x-\sqrt{2})^2-1)}{\sqrt{2}(1+x^2)^2}$$
that vanishes at $x=-1+\sqrt{2}$ and $x=1+\sqrt{2}$. We are interested only in the first value since $-1+\sqrt{2}<1$ the other is bigger than one. On interval $[0,1]$ we get then that $f(x)$ is increasing for $x\in [0,\sqrt{2}-1)$ and decreasing for $x\in(\sqrt{2}-1,1]$ with the maximum at $x=\sqrt{2}-1$. By Mean Valued Theorem for integrals we have
$$\int^1_0f(x)\,dx=f(\xi)(1-0)=f(\xi)$$
for some $\xi\in(0,1)$. By the above observations then we have
$$f(\xi)=\int^1_0f(x)\,dx\leqslant f(\sqrt{2}-1)\int^1_0\,dx=f(\sqrt{2}-1)$$
and $$f(\xi)=\int^1_0f(x)\,dx\geqslant f(0)\int^1_0\,dx=f(0)=1$$

Comment: I understand!! Could we get a better approximation if we use the second mean value theorem for integrals? This theorem is the following, isn't it? 
On $[a, b]$ let $f$ be monotone and $f'$ and $g$ be continuous. Then there exists a $\xi \in (a, b)$ with \begin{equation*}\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\, dx=f(a)\int_a^{\xi}g(x)\, dx+f(b)\int_{\xi}^bg(x)\, dx\end{equation*} Do we choose as $f(x):=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $g(x):=e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar I think you only need $f$ monotone and $g$ integrable. Anyways you could then find estimates for each of those two integrals. Maybe you get better bounds.

Comment: Ah ok! So, do we chose as $f$ the function $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and as $g$ the function  $e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}$ or otherwise around?

Comment: you can try both combinations, they are both monotonic and integrable on $[0,1]$. see which is better.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious thing to do is to tkae $f(x)=\frac{e^{x/\sqrt2}}{1+x^2}$. It is then a matter of finding the sup and inf of $f$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

$$f'(x)=\frac{\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1+x^2)-(2x)\Big)e^\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

The derivative is $0$ when $x=\sqrt 2 \pm 1$